# Java not creating Image file (Using ImageIO)

Tags: java, image, matrix, javax.imageio

I have been given an assignment where I have to read two images from secondary memory and I have to store them in two separate matrices. Then I have to multiply these matrices and convert the resultant matrix back to an image and store it in the HDD. Here is the code:

```
package ISI;

import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.PixelGrabber;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

class ImageMultiplication {

  BufferedImage img1, img2;
  File f1, f2;
  int matrix1[][], matrix2[][], matrix3[][];
  int w,h;

  ImageMultiplication() { 
      img1 = img2 = null; 
      f1 = f2 = null;
      w = 500;
      h = 400;
  }

  void readImages() throws IOException {
      f1 = new File("image1.jpg");
      f2 = new File("image2.jpg");
      img1 = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
      img2 = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
      img1 = ImageIO.read(f1);
      img2 = ImageIO.read(f2);
      System.out.println("\nReading of images complete");
  }

  void convertToMatrix() {
      int [] array1 = new int[w*h];
      matrix1 = new int[h][w];
      int [] array2 = new int[w*h];
      matrix2 = new int[w][h];
      matrix3 = new int[h][h];
      try {
          img1.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, array1, 0, w);
          img2.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, array2, 0, w);

      }
      catch(Exception e) {
          System.out.println("\nInterrupted");
      }

      int count=0;

      for(int i=0;i<h;i++) {
          for(int j=0;j<w;j++) {
              if(count == array1.length)
                  break;
              matrix1[i][j] = array1[count];
              count++;
          }
      }

      count=0;

      for(int i=0;i<w;i++) {
          for(int j=0;j<h;j++) {
              if(count == array2.length)
                  break;
              matrix2[i][j]=array2[count];
              count++;
          }
      }

      int sum = 0, c, d, k;
      for (c = 0; c < h; c++) {
          for (d = 0; d < h; d++) {
              for (k = 0; k < w; k++) 
                  sum = sum + matrix1[c][k] * matrix2[k][d]; 
          matrix3[c][d] = sum;
          sum = 0;
          }
      }  

      /* Comment snippet 1
      for(int i = 0; i<h; i++) {
          for(int j = 0; j<h; j++)
              System.out.print(" "+matrix3[i][j]);
          System.out.println();
      }
      */        
  }

  void convertMatrixToImage() {
      BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(w, h,  BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
      try {
          for(int i=0; i<h; i++) {
              for(int j=0; j<h; j++) {
                  int a = matrix3[i][j];
                  Color newColor = new Color(a,a,a);
                  image.setRGB(j,i,newColor.getRGB());
              }
          }
          ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("Output.jpg"));
      }
      catch(Exception e) {}
      System.out.println(image.toString());
      System.out.println("\nThe output image has been generated!");         
  }

  public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
      ImageMultiplication i = new ImageMultiplication();
      i.readImages();
      i.convertToMatrix();
      i.convertMatrixToImage();
  }

}
```

The file executes with no problem.

[See](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SekiQ.png)

The problem is, However, that no image file is created or written in the directory ( `void convertMatrixToImage()` ). If I uncomment (`comment snippet 1`), I get a 2D matrix as the output on the console window where each index shows a numeric value which I am assuming to be the pixed RGB value. But there is no sign whatsoever of any image file ever being created. Can somebody please help me out?

Note: I have tried converting the *array* to *byte array* and then writing the image file and I have tried other methods as well, but nothing seems to work. I tried it even on Windows but it also has the same problem. Nowhere is the *Output.jpg* being created/written.

Comment: `catch(Exception e) {}`??!! Seriously, don't do this. At least print the stacktrace, since how else will you know if a critical exception has been thrown?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I know we should not do this but if any exception occurred, then the program would have terminated as no exception handling is happening here. But this is certainly not the case because the code executes perfectly.

Comment: @c2yCharlie *"then the program would have terminated as no exception handling is happening here"* - No, that's actually wrong `try-catch` IS handling the exception, but it's just ignoring it. *"I know we should not do this"* - Then don't, do something useful about it, it's going to provide you with the very information YOU need to solve your problem. *"But this is certainly not the case because the code executes perfectly."* - Then why are we having this conversation? This advice is been given to you to try and help YOU understand and solve YOUR issues

Comment: Chill man...I didn't know that try - catch can sometimes ignore the exception. My bad. Anyways, thanks for the help mate.

Comment: @c2yCharlie Just trying to drag you up, kicking and screaming, to be a better developer ;) - Never assume "just because it works, it's right" - code that works the first time always worries me ;)

Comment: sure mate...will keep that in mind

Comment: Your definition of perfection and mine don't match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run your, modified code to print the `Exception`, I get...

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Color parameter outside of expected range: Red Green Blue
    at java.awt.Color.testColorValueRange(Color.java:310)
    at java.awt.Color.<init>(Color.java:395)
    at java.awt.Color.<init>(Color.java:369)
    at javaapplication194.ImageMultiplication.convertMatrixToImage(JavaApplication194.java:102)
    at javaapplication194.ImageMultiplication.main(JavaApplication194.java:118)
```

Now, I'll be honest, I had no idea what this "really" means, but I know it has something to do with "color"

So I had a look back over the conversation code...

```
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
            int a = matrix3[i][j];
            Color newColor = new Color(a, a, a);
            image.setRGB(j, i, newColor.getRGB());
        }
    }
    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("Output.jpg"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And noted...

```
int a = matrix3[i][j];
Color newColor = new Color(a, a, a);
image.setRGB(j, i, newColor.getRGB());
```

This seems very weird to me for a number of reasons...

1. You use `getRGB` to get the color as a packed `int` value
2. You try and make a new color from this packed `int`
3. You use `getRGB` to return a packed `int` from a color based on a packed `int`

All of which seems, wrong and unnecessary, you already have a packed `int` RGB value, why not just use

```
int a = matrix3[i][j];
//Color newColor = new Color(a, a, a);
image.setRGB(j, i, a);
```

adding this, the error goes away and the image is created